# What kind of timestamp is in the form '07:df:01:0e:0e:28:2a:39'?

Tags: java, date, format

I am trying to receive trap from UCS and convert them into JSON format.

But, I came across a time format like this:

```
07:df:01:0e:0e:28:2a:39
```

I'm unfamiliar with this format, and don't know how to convert it to other formats (like HH:MM:SS-YY:MM:DD), or anything else human-readable.

Using Java (or just generally), how do I parse this particular format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Data and Time in  a "standard Textual Convention which is defined in the SNMPv2-TC. "

https://communities.bmc.com/thread/52383
http://www.webnms.com/net-snmp/help/developing_management_applications/datatypes/textual_conventions/tcs_dateandtime.html

```
  @Test
public void test() {
    String time = "07:df:01:0e:0e:28:2a:39";
    time = time.replaceFirst(":", "");
    String[] values = time.split(":");
    assertEquals(7, values.length);
    for(String value : values){
        System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(value, 16) + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for answering ...it works but can  it be done like in miliseconds from epoch time...

Comment: Technically: epoch time is number of seconds since 01.01.1970 00:00. :-]  To get what you need use java.util.Date class and it's methods (setYear etc.). After that use Date.getTime(). Or Calendar. Or Something from  new date/Time library in Java 8

Answer (score 0):

If you convert groups to decimal format you'll get the following 07df=2015, 01=01, 0e=14 etc. At the end you see 2015011414404257. I think it is pretty clear.

Comment: how do you know how group two elements separated by colon?